# xhtml2pdf get pagination to work with dynamic content

Tags: python, django, pagination, xhtml2pdf

I am making an invoice pdf template generated within a django view and testing for when lots of content gets added to a table. That it will continue onto the next page if there is too much content on the table on the first page. The problem im facing is that the content just disappears off the table on the first page never to be seen again. I event tested with the pagination example in the docs.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @page {
        size: letter portrait;
        @frame header_frame {           /* Static frame */
            -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 40pt;
        }
        @frame col1_frame {             /* Content frame 1 */
            left: 44pt; width: 245pt; top: 90pt; height: 632pt;
        }
        @frame col2_frame {             /* Content frame 2 */
            left: 323pt; width: 245pt; top: 90pt; height: 632pt;
        }
        @frame footer_frame {           /* Static frame */
            -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 20pt;
        }
    }
</style>
<head>

<body>
    <div id="header_content">Lyrics-R-Us</div>
    <div id="footer_content">(c) - page <pdf:pagenumber>
        of <pdf:pagecount>
    </div>
    <p>Old MacDonald had a farm. EIEIO.</p>
    <p>And on that farm he had a cow. EIEIO.</p>
    <p>With a moo-moo here, and a moo-moo there.</p>
    <p>Here a moo, there a moo, everywhere a moo-moo.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But that does not show any pages for me just the first one with the page number and none of the text within the `<p>` tags are displayed. I raised an issue on the github page but thought i might be able to get a solution here.